# Can I use FileInputStream without giving it a path right at the start

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, processing, fileinputstream

I am trying to upload a file to a database (a .mp4 file to be specific). But when I run my code the file path is not yet chosen because, in the program a window pops up where you can select a file you want to upload. Is there a way to achieve this?

The problem I am having with FileInputStream is that it asks for a file path at the start of my program but the path is still uncertain at that point.

Greetings Pygesux

This is where I try to INSERT into the db

```
public void draw() {
    open.draw();
    openText.draw();
    if (video != null) {
        upload.draw();
        uploadText.draw();
    }
}
public void mouseClick() {
    if (open.mouseOverMe()) {
        selectInput("Select a file to process:", "fileSelected");
    } else if (upload.mouseOverMe()) {
        uploadFile();
    }
}
public void fileSelect(File selection) {
    video = selection;
}
public void uploadFile() {
    try {
        con = database.getConnect();
        java.sql.PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO filmpje (filmpje) VALUES (?)");
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(video);
        statement.setBlob(1, input);
        statement.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: FileInputStream needs a file. You need to create it once you know the file. Try pasting a small piece of code to show where you have the problem.

Comment: The solution is to simply avoid creating the `FileInputStream` until you have all the required info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you do not create FileInputStream after the path is chosen?

Make a method, that take path, and then creates the FileInputStream, and do other job. Call this method after you know your path, after user eneter it, and accept by pressing button/enter (it is your app logic).

Comment: I am creating a fileinputstream for using setBlob() in jdbc for saving a file to my database. And FileInputStream gets initialized in a method which gets run when you hit the button but the program doesnt run at all when I use FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(path)); because it gives a FileNotFoundException. Which makes sense because the path is "" at the start of the program.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to use `selectInput()` correct? The reference example is not super clear. The program continues to run while the user selects a file, so you get an error if you try to run code that requires the filename. Here's an example that tests if the file is set yet or not. You would need to update it for your particular needs:

```
String input;


void setup() {
  size(500,200);

  selectInput("Select a file...", "fileSelector");
}


void draw() {
  background(255);

  fill(0);
  noStroke();
  if (input == null) {
    text("No file selected.", 20,height/2);
  }
  else {
    text(input, 20,height/2);
  }

}

void fileSelector(File selection) {
  if (selection == null) {
    // window closed or user hit cancel button
  }
  else {
    input = selection.getAbsolutePath();
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem isnt that the program tries to initialize FileInputStream while using selectInput() it is that when adding the initialize statement for FileInputStream it tries to initialize right at the start (I think its called when building the application)